# In which way, Jetpack Compose refresh its Views?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Compose introduction, it says Compose can refresh the view which needs to update.
[image]

The question is how Compose knows which view to update? Dose Compose have a binding between view and data in bottom layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more detailed information in [Under the hood of Jetpack Compose Part 2 article by Leland Richardson](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd), this answer uses article as reference and quotes most from it

Let's say you have a counter Composable such as

```
@Composable
fun Counter() {
 var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
 Button(
   text="Count: $count",
   onPress={ count += 1 }
 )
```

This is the code that we would write, but let’s look at what the compiler does.

When the compiler sees the Composable annotation, it inserts additional parameters and calls into the body of the function.

First, the compiler adds a call to the composer.start method and passes it a compile time generated key integer.

```
fun Counter($composer: Composer) {
 $composer.start(123)
 var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
 Button(
   text="Count: $count",
   onPress={ count += 1 }
 )
 $composer.end()
}
```

When this composer executes it does the following:

1. Composer.start gets called and stores a group object
2. remember inserts a group object the value that mutableStateOf
   returns, the state instance, is stored.
3. Button stores a group, followed by each of its parameters.
4. And then finally we arrive at composer.end.

The generated code the compiler creates for this counter has a composer.start and compose.end. Whenever Counter executes, the runtime understands that when it calls count.value, it’s reading the property of an appmodel instance. At runtime, whenever we call compose.end, we optionally return a value.

```
$composer.end()?.updateScope { nextComposer ->
 Counter(nextComposer)
}
```

Then we can call an `updateScope` method on that value with a lambda that tells the runtime `how to restart this Composable`, if it needs to. This is equivalent to the `lambda that LiveData would otherwise` receive.

For functions that read inputs they use slot tables and check the difference based on stability of inputs. More details about how they are stored and optimized is available in the article.

Answer (score 1):

In Jetpack Compose, the framework uses a declarative UI approach. This means that you describe your UI using Compose functions and Compose takes care of updating the UI when the underlying data changes. Compose does not rely on traditional data-binding mechanisms commonly found in XML-based Android layouts.

Here's how Compose knows which views to update:

1. **Immutable UI Components**: In Compose, you create UI components as immutable functions that take data as input and return UI elements. These UI components are essentially functions that take some data and return a description of how the UI should look based on that data.
2. **Recompositions**: Compose keeps track of the dependencies between your UI components and the data they use. When the underlying data changes, Compose automatically triggers a process called "recomposition." During recomposition, Compose re-evaluates the UI component functions and updates only the parts of the UI that have changed.
3. **Diffing Algorithm**: Compose has a diffing algorithm that efficiently calculates the difference between the previous UI state and the new UI state. It then applies only the necessary updates to the actual UI elements. This is much more efficient than manually updating individual views in a traditional imperative approach.
4. **No Explicit Binding**: Unlike some other UI frameworks, Compose does not require you to establish explicit data bindings between your views and data. Instead, you rely on the declarative nature of your UI components. When you recompose a part of your UI with updated data, Compose automatically figures out how to update the corresponding views.

In summary, Compose knows which views to update through its internal dependency tracking and diffing mechanism. You don't need to create explicit bindings between views and data; Compose handles this automatically, making it easier to build dynamic and efficient UIs in Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack Compose we have `MutableState` and the composer observe these value and whenever the value changes it will recompose the `@Composable` functions in which the value is used doesn't recompose the composables where the value is not used.